# Add checked = true via programming

Tags: c#, toolstrip, checked

I have been adding items to tool strip by programming but the issue is that I need to add checked property to it.  Do not know how to do so.
Here is the code:

```
toolStripMenuItemAudioSampleRate.DropDownItems.Add("8 kHz", null, new EventHandler(mnuAudioSamplingRate_Click));
toolStripMenuItemAudioSampleRate.Checked = (samplingRate == 8000);//Checks if the there is no vid device
```

Now I know that it will work wrong because I have added checked property to `toolStripMenuItemAudioSampleRate`
not the `8 kHz`.  I am trying to add this property to the dynamically added items.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "add this property", I assume you mean "set this property".  Am I correct in saying that?

Comment: yes you are correct i am not native english speaker so mistakes are always there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901932/add-checked-true-via-programming/4902001#4902001) code fancier, I suggest removing `new EventHandler`, which is always redundant, and using object initializer:

```
toolStripMenuItemAudioSampleRate.DropDownItems.Add (
    new ToolStripMenuItem ("8 kHz", null, mnuAudioSamplingRate_Click) {
        Checked = (samplingRate == 8000)
    });
```

Comment: gud style worked by little modification that is instead of 'ToolStripItem' replaced 'ToolStripMenuItem'

Comment: Im Loving it.It simply reduced my LOC to Half.Great!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the `Add(String, Image, EventHandler)` helper method to create the drop down item, make your own `ToolStripMenuItem`, set it to checked, and then add it to the list.

```
ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem("8 kHz", null, new EventHandler(mnuAudioSamplingRate_Click));
item.Checked = (samplingRate == 8000);
toolStripMenuItemAudioSampleRate.DropDownItems.Add(item);
```

Comment: since when does ToolStripItem's class have a Checked property? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.aspx

Comment: @Jean-Christophe Fortin: Edited to reflect that you need `ToolStripMenuItem` for checked. I didn't spend enough time on msdn to see that `ToolStripItem` was a parent class since no class names were used in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
toolStripMenuItemAudioSampleRate.DropDownItems["8 kHz"].Checked = (samplingRate == 8000)
```

That might do what you want.  It might be a good idea to hold on to these dynamically added items in an array somewhere, so that you don't have to use this ugly syntax.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an Decorator(GOF Design Pattern)
http://www.exciton.cs.rice.edu/JavaResources/DesignPatterns/book/hires/pat4dfso.htm

Comment: At least can I know why you VoteDown ? The Adapter Pattern is made for  adding responsibilities to individual objects dynamically and transparently.

Comment: I didn't vote down but I too can see no connection between Adapter pattern and the question being asked.

Comment: `ToolStripMenuItem` is standard framework class and already has desired functionality, he just needed to set its property.

Comment: Oups.. you're right it's the Decorator pattern I want to say. Otherwise, at first @Afnan say he want to "add" the property to a object which it exactly what the Decorator(my mistake) does. I wasn't aware that ToolStripMenuItem have already the property.